# Select highest time of day

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to select the highest time of different datetimes. This is my query now :

```
SELECT MAX(`afgewerkt tablet datum`)
FROM `psttodo-uit`
WHERE `Hostess Code = '010'
AND MONTH(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) = MONTH('04-14')
AND DAY(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) = DAY('04-14')
```

But I'm getting an SQL error like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'afgewerkt tablet datum`) = MONTH('04-14') AND DAY(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) = DA' at line 3

What am I doing wrong? And it this the correct way?

Comment: missing the closing backtick on Hostess Code

Comment: `'04-14'` is **NOT** a valid mysql date/time string, and your `month()` and `day()` calls are going to be returning an SQL `NULL`, meaning you'll never match **ANY** records.

Comment: In my php code I have: $date = strtotime($key);
                $date = date('Y-m-d',$date); and I'm inserting that but still NULL. Not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing backtick in the WHERE clause.